# Update UI before running the rest of method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have a long-running operation that have to be done in UI thread (involves UI elements that cannot be freezed). I want to display a busy indicator before running the operation.

```
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
LongRunningMethod();
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Of course this does not work because rendering does not occur until the operation finishes. I tried to use Task.Yield() to run the rest of method asynchronously:

```
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
await Task.Yield();
LongRunningMethod();
```

This also does not work, as far as I understand, because the rest of the method is prioritized higher than rendering operation.

How can I do it using TPL?

**UPD:** `LongRunningMethod` cannot be run in a separate thread by its nature (works with complex WPF 3D models), and anyway I cannot afford to make changes in it now. So please don't offer solutions based on running it completely or partially on a separate thread.

Comment: where are you using TPL?

Comment: @l3arnon don't understand. What do you mean by "where"?

Comment: The first code sample doesn't use TPL. You ask how to do it using TPL. How is TPL related?

Comment: @l3arnon aren't await/async and Task parts of TPL?

Comment: @AlekseyShubin `Task.Yield` does not strictly create what you understand as a `Task`

Comment: @Gusdor ok maybe I misunderstand how Task.Yield() works. From the MSDN description I thought it just post the rest of the method to synchronization context. Exactly what I need, except I need to place it with low priority, to ensure that UI repaint occurs before it.

Comment: Is this a windows forms or wpf application?

Comment: @Gusdor WPF application

Comment: You need to split any long running operation which involves UI updates into sub tasks. If long running, invoke the parts which you can offload to a background thread and then update the UI, perhaps through the `IProgress<T>` interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to break UI method execution, then you have to use `async`/`await`.

Something like (untested)

```
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
await Task.Run(() => await Task.Delay(1)); // here method will exit and repaint will occurs
LongRunningMethod();
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

But depending on how long method runs, you may want to put it completely into another thread (`Task`, `BackgroundWorker`) and only invoke methods when you need to be in UI thread.

Comment: Thanks! Though it seems like a hack, but anyway it works. I think I will go with your solution for now. Will not mark as answer yet in case someone will advice more straightforward way.

Comment: I had a compiler error on the await before Task.Delay(). Removing it solved the error & works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the code: I got it to work by adding async : await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1));

Answer (score 2):

This is quite trivial when you learn how to async and await work. You can read about that [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Your problem is that you are never starting any asynchronous work - `Task.Yield` is already called from the UI context and will do nothing.

Try this:

```
async Task MyProcess() //the Task is returned implicitly
{
    busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await LongRunningMethod(); //the work here is done in a worker thread
    busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //this line executes back on the ui context
}

Task LongRunningMethod() //the Async suffix is a convention to differentiate overloads that return Tasks
{
    var result1 = await Task.Run(() => /* do some processing */ ); //we are actually starting an asynchronous task here.

    //update some ui elements here

    var result2 = await Task.Run(() => /* do some more processing */ );

    //update some ui elements here
}
```

Comment: Creating an`async` method with a name ending in `Async` that just calls `Task.Run` is an anti-pattern because most `async` methods do not use a thread whereas `Task.Run` does so it is a bit misleading

Comment: As far as I understand, Task.Run() will run the method in another thread. As I mentioned, I cannot run LongRunningMethod in another thread (because it uses UI elements).

Comment: @NedStoyanov in this sample `LongRunningMethodAsync` is not an `async` method. If you had two methods with the same parameters but one returns a task, the suffix allows you to compile. You should take it up with Microsoft's design team. Arguably, you should have two overloads but this pattern allowed me to show common `async/await` usage without changing the existing worker method (which may be immutable in his code). Don't be a hater dear! ;)

Comment: @AlekseyShubin can `LongRunningMethod` be changed to resemble `MyProcess()` as above? This pattern is the correct way to run asynchronous work and update the without freezing the ui. `async` methods can be nested.

Comment: @Gusdor, definitiely not a hater, just mentioning what I have learned from others. Sorry if it came across the wrong way it was definitely not intended that way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your long running method is not `async` you should be able to call it inside `Task.Run` and `await` the result, or even better use `TaskFactory.StartNew` and pass in `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

```
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
await TaskFactory.StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod(),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

On a side note, you need to be careful with `Task.Yield` because in some scenarios such as with `WindowsForms` the task scheduled on the `SynchronizationContext` has a higher priority than repainting the window so you can make your UI non-responsive if you repeatedly call `Task.Yield`, such as in a while loop.

Comment: The same as above: TaskFactory.StartNew() will run the method in another thread, and I need to run it in the same thread.

Comment: Maybe you can just push the blocking calls into another thread by `awaiting` other methods?